# MongoDB create table with primarykey and reference to other table

Tags: mongodb, reference

I've check on other threads and tried the codes for MongoDB but none of them works and many of the are very confusing to me as this is my first time learning MongoDB, I have 2 table, subject table and lecturer table

```
Subject collection subject_id(PK)
db.subject.insert([
{"subject_id":"IT301"),     
"subject_name": "Computing",
"credit_hour": "6"},
{"subject_id":"IT302",      
"subject_name": "Networking",
"credit_hour": "6"}])

Lecturer collection lecturer_id(PK)
db.lecturer.insert(
{"lecturer_id":"12345",     
"lecturer_name": "John Doe"})
```

How do I reference that both the subject is taught by this 1 lecturer? I've seen online something like this:

```
{"lecturer_id":ObjectId("12345"),       
"lecturer_name": "John Doe"
"subject_id":[IT301, IT302]}    //This line added, but it doesn't work
```

error stating that IT301 is not defined.
I am only using commandprompt on windows without any IDE

Comment: In ```lecture_id``` collection you are using references is a way to get a reference to another collection, but you have to turn that ```IT301``` into ```ObjectId``` thus you can search for the reference to another collection.

Comment: @juliansalas um sorry, but i dont quite understand. I did make both the subject_id into ObjectId already.

Answer (score 0):

- MongoDB used to have collections(corresponding to tables in SQL/Oracle).
- Each collection used to have multiple documents(corresponding to different 
  rows of tables in SQL/Oracle).
- It used to have different properties like json({"name":"test"})
  (corresponding to different columns of tables in SQL/Oracle).
- MongoDB does not support primary Key and foreign key, but we can do this by 
  embedding documents.

  For your problem,Lecturer collection should have below properties:

  {"lecturer_id":ObjectId("12345"),
    "lecturer_name": "John Doe"
    "subject_id":[IT301, IT302]}

  This will help you to embedded your documents from two different collection.

Happy Coding

Comment: "subject_id":ObjectId("IT301")   , here you can directly store IT301. No need to cast to ObjectId

Comment: Might be your mongoDB queries are not correct. Please use below queries for your problems:

Subject Collection query------- 
         db.subject.insert([
             {"subject_id":"IT301",     
              "subject_name": "Computing",
              "credit_hour": "6"},
             {"subject_id":"IT302",      
              "subject_name": "Networking",
             "credit_hour": "6"}])
     
Lecturer Collection query-------

          db.lecturer.insert(
          {"lecturer_id":"12345",     
         "lecturer_name": "John Doe",
         "subject_id":["IT301","IT302"]})